# No response from jQuery validation script

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make a simple registration form and use jQuery to validate it. There is no sign of attempt of validation. I cannot figure out what's wrong. On submission, there is no response. I don't get a response even If I were just switching between empty fields.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="general.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  (function($,W,D){
      var JQUERY4U = {};
      JQUERY4U.UTIL =
      {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
          //form validation rules
          $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
              firstname: "required",
              lastname: "required",
              email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
              },
              password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
              },
              agree: "required"
            },
            messages: {
              firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
              lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
              password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
              },
              email: "Please enter a valid email address",
              agree: "Please accept our policy"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              form.submit();
            }
          });
        }
      }

      //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
      $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
      });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <form action="#" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
      <h2>User Registration</h2>

      <div id="form-content">
        <fieldset>

          <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
          </div>

          <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
          </div>

          <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email"/>
          </div>

          <div class="fieldgroup">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
          </div>

          <div class="fieldgroup">
            <p class="right">By clicking register you agree to our <a target="_blank" href="/policy">policy</a>.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit"/>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <div class="fieldgroup">
        <p>Already registered? <a href="/login">Sign in</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjH7U/

Comment: Thanks guys, I have corrected the order of the script tags, however in the following source code I'm unable to get the validation done in real time. Why is that ? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bfnSH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script tags are in the wrong order. The jQuery validation framework requires jQuery to work. So, you must move your jQuery script tag above the jQuery validation script tag. They load in the order you put them in.

Also, the final script tag that contains your code should be moved below the html that lays out your form UI. Again, it's the same issue. Your code is being called before the html has been loaded into the DOM. This is why it doesn't work. See this JSBin for a working example:

http://jsbin.com/yeseraku/1/edit?html,output

The working code:

```
<html>
<head>  

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <form action="#" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

        <h2>User Registration</h2>

        <div id="form-content">
            <fieldset>

                <div class="fieldgroup">
                    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldgroup">
                    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldgroup">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldgroup">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldgroup">
                    <p class="right">By clicking register you agree to our <a target="_blank" href="/policy">policy</a>.</p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit"/>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <p>Already registered? <a href="/login">Sign in</a>.</p>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D){
        var JQUERY4U = {};

        JQUERY4U.UTIL =
        {
            setupFormValidation: function()
            {
                //form validation rules
                $("#register-form").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstname: "required",
                        lastname: "required",
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        password: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 5
                        },
                        agree: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                        lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                        password: {
                            required: "Please provide a password",
                            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                        },
                        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        agree: "Please accept our policy"
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
        $(D).ready(function($) {
            JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
        });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good catch. I was about to say how I made a jsfiddle and everything worked just fine ;).

Comment: Thanks guys, I have corrected the order of the script tags, however in the following source code I'm unable to get the validation done in real time. Why is that ? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bfnSH)

Comment: @user3296203 your script tags are all relative paths. So, the browser is looking for your js scripts within jsfiddle's domain and it doesn't find them. This leads jQuery's `$` object not existing, which causes an error. Open up your browser's console and you will see the error.